# What is the etymology of the word 'subir'? / ¿Cuál es la etimología de la palabra 'subir'?

Tags: etimología

For many years I've been asking myself this single and simple question : why ***subir***, that should logically come from the latin ***sub-ire*** that we can translate into **go down** in English, does mean **go up** in Spanish!? What is then the real etymology of this word?

Desde que estudié latín en la escuela hace 6 años, siempre me pregunté esta sencilla pregunta: ¿por qué **subir**, que en mi opinión vendría de la palabra latina ***sub-ire*** que quiere decir literalmente **ir hacia abajo** (**bajar**), tiene el significado opuesto a la traducción literal y etimológica? ¿Cuál es entonces la verdadera etimología de esta palabra?

Comment: From www.rae.es/subir -> `Del lat. subīre, llegar, avanzar, arriba`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Como tu lo mencionas, subire esta compuesto por `sub` (bajo/abajo) + `ire` (ir/avanzar) y si es la etimología correcta, sin embargo lo estas viendo con el enfoque opuesto, es decir, `subire` no significa `ir/avanzar hacia abajo` sino lo contrario `ir/avanzar DESDE abajo` (**`↑`**)